# Как проверять сеть во время стрима

Tags: java, android

У меня возник вопрос относящееся к видео стриму. Например видео воспроизводится онлайн, во время воспроизведения нужно ли проверять соединение с сетью каждую секунду? Если да, то каким образом. Потому что я с запросами я работал только для того чтобы получать JSON строку. Или вообще как правильно построить структуру воспроизведения видео?

Comment: Вам зачем именно проверять соединение? От этого зависит решение. При воспроизведении в общем случае соединение проверять нет смысла - видео само либо дойдет, либо не дойдет.

Comment: Вот например в приложении ютьюба во время воспроизведения если подключение разорвался то progressBar выскакивает. Значит там проверяется или нет?

Comment: Скорей всего при разрыве соединения бросается искючение, или через колбек вызывается какой то метод, вот это и обрабатывайте.

Comment: Вот в том то и дело. Как проверяется разрыв соединения?

Comment: В каждом случае надо смотреть отдельно. Ещё раз повторюсь, надо проверять не состояние сети на телефоне, а корректно обрабатывать исключения или колбеки, которые предоставляет та или иная библиотека.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужен бродкаст ресивер, который будем уведомлять ваше приложение каждый раз когда состояние сети будет меняться.

```
public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
            if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getDetailedState() == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.CONNECTED) {
                Log.d("Network", "Соединение есть");
            } else if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.getDetailedState() == NetworkInfo.DetailedState.DISCONNECTED) {
                Log.d("Network", "Соединение оборванно");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И не забываем прописать в манифесте

```
<receiver
    android:name=".receivers.NetworkReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Спасибо, не проверил. но мысль понял!

Comment: В этом нет смысла. Такое решение не заметит сетевых проблем дальше первого хопа.

Answer (score 2):

Возможно, вам на самом деле нужна не информация о том, доступен или нет сервер, а информация о том, достаточно или недостаточно плееру данных для работы. Если сервер на какое-то время отвалился, но буфера хватило, то пользователю это неважно. Пользователю будет важно, если сервер доступен, но скорости не хватает.

Поищите в библиотеке плеера колбэк, который возвращает статус. Если вы используете [ExoPlayer](https://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/) (я надеюсь, вы используете его, а не стандартный?), то в колбэк [ExoPlayer.EventListener](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.EventListener.html) в метод [onPlayerStateChanged()](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.EventListener.html#onPlayerStateChanged-boolean-int-) может вернуться статус [STATE_BUFFERING](http://google.github.io/ExoPlayer/doc/reference/com/google/android/exoplayer2/ExoPlayer.html#STATE_BUFFERING), при получении которого можно показать пользователю прогресс-бар.

Comment: спасибо. Информация была полезной очень. Даа я понял, что мне нужна информация о данных в буфере. Про библиотеку я не знал

Comment: А что думаете насчет библиотеки Vitamio, где то прочитал о нем, но не совсем понял что он делает

Comment: Vitamio не использовать. И, по-моему, она денег стоит, не?

Comment: Спасибо. Не знаю